# how to group one2many list view inside another model in openerp 6.1?

Tags: odoo

In my sale.order, i have added a new one2many field sale_bom for showing the bill of material lines. Whenever i add a sale order line, if the product have a bill of material then its bom lines should be shown under the new field sale_bom.

I found the way to group the sale_bom lines by sale_order_lines using `context="{'group_by':'sale_order_line'}"` in web client and gtk client of openerp v6.0.3 but it is not working in openerp v6.1
[image]
Is there any way to group in openerp v6.1 web client?

Answer (score 1):

in openerp6.1 webclient it is not possible to please use  GTK client. or provide a link for the tree view in right panel .

Comment: It is something I have created in openerp v6.0.3 and works perfectly. But now my client need to migrate it to 6.1 and I'm stuck in this

Comment: yes in **6.0** it was working to show o2m file listview with group_by.
but in **6.1** it is not possible.
one alternative is to provide a link for the same for groupby in context of action

Comment: yeah, i have provided the link, but they need to see it in the saleorder for reference because the unit price of the sale order line will change to the total of unit price of the bom lines. that why im still trying to find a way to get webclient grouping.

Comment: they either you have to develop somthing at web side and patch or introduce new module. or search on internet for the same module available or not . still i have not developed it else i can provide you ref for same .

Comment: I'm trying on it. If i get it i will surely post it. Anyway thank you Ruchir Shukla