# BOM structure inside manufacturing order.(tree view inside a model) openerp

Tags: odoo

I need to add a new page inside manufacture order which shows the tree view of bom of the main product.Something like the image below
[image]

Does anyone have idea about it?I need it in 6.0.3

Answer (score 1):

If you are using new web client i.e. 6.1+ this feature you are asking that "add a new page inside manufacture order which shows the tree view of bom"  Does not works,

Pure Solution is use GTK client or Go Implement the missing feature in web client.

or What you can do is yo can provide some Right hand side short cut act windows which will open the  new view which is expected by you.

and IF I am not missing anything then this matches with your older post : [how to group one2many list view inside another model in openerp 6.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153743/how-to-group-one2many-list-view-inside-another-model-in-openerp-6-1)  ;)

Thank You

Comment: I need this feature in openerp v6.0.3.

Comment: @AnomA : this feature purely not available in web client in side the view, yes you have to crate separate view and you can trigger action i already said In my answer. Else you have to create new widget in web client for the same, which is bit tricky ;)